# Is $p(\sqrt2)=2$, where $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

> Let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2 +\sqrt{−2}$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers. Evaluate $p(\sqrt2)$.

My attempt:  Take  $x= \sqrt 2 +\sqrt{−2}$, which implies $x-\sqrt 2=\sqrt {-2}\tag1$

Squaring both sides of $(1)$ gives
$$(x-\sqrt 2)^2=(\sqrt {-2})^2$$ and thus $$x^2-2x\sqrt 2+2=-2 .$$

So, $p(x)=x^2-2x\sqrt 2+4=0$ and hence $p(\sqrt2)=2-4+4=2$.

Comment: $p(x)=x^2-2x\sqrt 2+4$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: im  not getting  why @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: Because $\sqrt 2 \notin \mathbb Q$.

Comment: The coefficients have to be in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** (For a suitable choice of branch of $\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}$), $$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{-2} = 2 e^{\pi i / 4} .$$

Comment: Okay that means  $x^4=16e^{\pi i}$.Am i right ?

Comment: Correct, and how can we simplify the right-hand side?

Comment: I think $x^4+16=0$ @Travis Willse

Comment: Correct, hence $x^4 + 16$ annihilates $\alpha := \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{-2}$, so all that remains is to show that $\alpha$ is not annihilated by a polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ of degree $\leq 4$. N.b. the hint could just as well be rephrased as observing that $\alpha^2 = 4 i$.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to see this is $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{2}(1+i)$

Hence $a^{2}=4i$ and $a^{4}=-16$ so $a^{4}+16=0$

Hence a polynomial having $a$ as a root is $x^{4}+16$

Now show that it is irreducible(by showing it has no rational(real) roots and no quadratic factors over $\Bbb{Q}[x]$) and hence it is the minimal polynomial .

Then evaluate at $\sqrt{2}$ to get $20$.